# Magento Category Pages Layout Set to 2 Col but 3 is showing?

Tags: magento

I have just start to design a template for Magento 1.6, It is a fresh install and I have made a folder for the app and skin! I am only creating files for the sections I need to edit for leaving the base template to do the rest. The only files I have edited are left_callout.phtml and header.phtml also I have edited the checkout.xml to move the My Cart to the left sidebar.

I have gone into the admin and changed the default category to 2 Columns and Left Sidebar as you can see in the image below:

[image: image1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQlLQ.jpg

But when I view the categories in the frontend it still shows 3 columns with both sidebars as you can see in the image below:

[image: image2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/70Xnf.jpg

I have disabled the cache in the admin! And I havn't edited the the XML files other than the checkout.xml Anyone know why this is happening? Also how come the otions are greyed out in the sub categories as you can see in the image above.

Answer (score 6):

**Write this code in local.xml (If not,then create) :-
Path :-magento_folder/app/design/frontend/mytheme(your_package)/neo(your_theme)/layout/local.xml
Try this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
</default>
<catalog_category_default>
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

**Set layout 
1column.phtml
2columns-right.phtml
3columns.phtml
Between template-tag depending on your requirements.
Onclicking any category,the page you will see should have the above selected layout template

Hope this may help you.**

Comment: Was so close to this solutions. My reference was category.xml but the handle "catalog_category_view" doesn't exist there. Instead there is "catalog_category_default" but using that doesn't work. I'm using 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 4):

I think you should edit page.xml and change under `<default>`

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">`
```

to

```
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">`
```

Maybe this help http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16838/